# Optimize run time of octave/matlab function

Tags: multithreading, matlab, octave

I am using the Google Earth Toolbox, for Octave, which is extremely similar to the same library made for MATLAB. See [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12954-google-earth-toolbox), for the MATLAB doc for the tool.

Unfortunately I am having a bit of trouble with a certain function: `ge_quiver`. This function creates a quiver plot and translates the result into KML code. My problem with it
is that it is a bit too slow for my liking.

For a data variable of 30x30 size, the function takes around 10 seconds to complete. This is fine, except for the fact that I am trying to make an animation quiver plot, with 23 other same sized data variables (24 total). Since Octave (and MATLAB for that matter) normally only runs on one thread, the whole thing is run serially, and takes 10*24 = 240 s.

I have tried `parfor` loops, but they have only removed 10 seconds from the total run time. I have a computer with 16 cores. Considering, this is embarrassingly parallel (no dependence between variables), this should ideally take:

10 seconds for the first 16 variables
+ 10 seconds for the 8 remaining variables
 
------------------------------------------------------
= 20 seconds total.

I haven't even tested arrayfun, because I don't know how to adapt my function (`p_ge_quiver`). Nonetheless, many have said that arrayfun will not make it faster.

The following code is approximately what I am trying to do. Remember that the variable
`data_u` is of size 30x30x24. Same thing for `data_v`, `lon`and `lat`.

```
...
...

[YYYY,MM,DD,HH,mm,ss] = ncdate(NCFILE);
date_s.year   = YYYY;
date_s.month  = MM;
date_s.day    = DD;
date_s.hour   = HH;
date_s.minute = mm;
date_s.second = ss;

TIMESTEP = 60;
parfor i = 1:size(data_u,3)
    dt     = TIMESTEP*i;
    kml(i) = p_ge_quiver(lon,lat,data_u,data_v,dt,TIMESTEP,data_s);
endparfor

...
...

function kml = p_ge_quiver(lon,lat,u,v,data_time,step,date_s)
% V_GE_QUIVER - Writes the quiver plot into KML.

    % Get date variables.
    YYYY = date_s.year;
    MM   = date_s.month;
    DD   = date_s.day;
    HH   = date_s.hour;
    mm   = date_s.minute;
    ss   = date_s.second;

    % Date format. Use Google's.
    F = 'yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ';

    % Start and end dates of data.
    tStart = datestr(datenum(YYYY,MM,DD,HH,mm+data_time,ss),F);
    tEnd   = datestr(datenum(YYYY,MM,DD,HH,mm+data_time+step,ss),F);

    % Quiver plot.
    kml = ge_quiver(lon,lat,u,v,'timeSpanStart', tStart, ...
                                'timeSpanStop' , tEnd  , ...
                                'visibility'   , 0     , ...
                                'lineColor'    , 'AAFFFFFF');



end
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I dont think `parfor` is implemented in Octave (it is recognized by the parser, but is just a regular `for`-loop for now).. It does have some functions for parallel computing in package `general`: http://octave.sourceforge.net/general/overview.html#ParallelComputing

Comment: I've read about that as well, but I did measure 10 second difference between for and parfor implementations. Very confusing.

Comment: I assume that (in Matlab at least) you opened a `matlabpool` before running your code? Though three 30-by-30-by-24 arrays isn't a lot of memory, who knows what `ge_quiver` is doing internally memory-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the problem is on what `ge_quiver` does internally which you don't show. Aside that, you should note that this language is designed to write vectorized code (and not only because of the difference in speed).

Looking at your code, you can simplify it lot (and this usually does have an effect in speed as well) by making use of a vectorized syntax:

```
step = 60;
dt = step:step:(step * size (data_u, 3));

## Get date variables.
YYYY = date_s.year;
MM   = date_s.month;
DD   = date_s.day;
HH   = date_s.hour;
mm   = date_s.minute;
ss   = date_s.second;

## Date format. Use Google's.
F = "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ";

tStart = datestr (datenum (YYYY, MM, DD, HH, mm + dt       , ss), F);
tEnd   = datestr (datenum (YYYY, MM, DD, HH, mm + dt + step, ss), F);
```

At this point, `tStart` and `tEnd` have all the dates that you need, one time per row. The only required loop is the following:

```
for i=1:rows(tStart)
    kml = ge_quiver (lon, lat, data_u, data_v, "timeSpanStart", tStart(i,:), ...
                                               "timeSpanStop" , tEnd(i,:)  , ...
                                               "visibility"   , 0          , ...
                                               "lineColor"    , "AAFFFFFF");
endfor
```

At this point is all dependent on what `ge_quiver` does. The mathworks site you linked appears as under maintenance. I looked into [the Google Earth toolbox website](http://code.google.com/p/googleearthtoolbox/) and couldn't find that function (they have a `ge_quiver3` function though).

I would argue that a function for this type of languages should allow for vector inputs, so go and confirm it. Maybe you don't need a loop at all.

Comment: I appreciate that code should be vectorized, but ge_quiver which is exactly the function that I would like to vectorize is not in your solution. Your solution will probably remove a few ms from my total run time, but that's about it.

Comment: @jhc well, there's no optimization left to do unless you tell you change `ge_quiver` or tell us how to use it. Your link is working again but I se still se no `ge_quiver` function there.

Comment: Yeah for some reason, the new toolbox does not have ge_quiver. Anyways, what I want to do is run each ge_quiver in a different thread, but I simply can't figure out how. parfor should have worked.

Comment: @jhc `parfor` in Octave maps to a normal `for`. To go that route your best choice is the [openmpi_ext package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/openmpi_ext/index.html). Look at the package examples. But really, you're pretty much passing the same data to `ge_quiver` multiple times. The right way to do this should be to fix `ge_quiver`. That's how this language is designed.